# Add wordpress(blogs) in asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Can I add wordpress(blogs) in an existing asp.net site?

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to enable PHP on your web server. If you are using IIS there's a [module](http://php.iis.net/) for it that you need to install and enable. Once you do this you could host a Wordpress site in IIS side by side with your ASP.NET application.

There's even a [WordPress installation](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/2.0/WebApplicationList.xml&appid=WordPress) in the Web PI.